# if $f$ is in weak $L^p$ and $\phi$ is $C_0^{1}$ then $f \ast \phi$ is in weak $L^p$

Tags: integration, analysis, functional-analysis, convolution

Okay, so I'd like to know if what I wrote in the title is true. Suppose that $f \in L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (weak $L^p$ space) and $\phi \in C_0^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ [or even $C_0^{\infty}$ if it matters, but I think not], where $C_0^1$ denotes continuously differentiable functions with compact support. is it true that 
$$ f \ast \phi \in L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
? if so, I'd also like to know how we can estimate this thing's weak norm - hopefully it'd be something that depends only on $f$'s weak norm and $||\phi||_{\infty}$. Is is true? If so does this result have a name?

Comment: Does  the subscript $0$ in  $C_0^1$    mean compactly supported functions, or those vanishing at infinity?

Comment: it means compactly supported - edited the question to avoid further confusion, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you cannot control the convolution by $\|\phi\|_\infty$. Take $f(x) = |x|^{-p/n}$ and let $\phi$ be a smooth function such that $\phi=1$ on the ball $B(0,R)$, and $0\le \phi\le 1$ everywhere. Then for $|x|\gg R$ we have 
$$f*\phi(x) \approx |B(0,R)| |x|^{-p/n}$$  where $ |B(0,R)|$ is the Lebesgue measure of the ball.  So, the weak $L^p$ norm gets multiplied by factor of about $ |B(0,R)|$.

The smoothness and even continuity of $\phi$ play no role: the relevant quantity is its $L^1$ norm. You need an analogue of Young's inequality  for weak $L^p$ spaces. Note that $p=1$ does not work:  weak $L^1$ does not even guarantee that $f*\phi$ is finite a.e. For $p>1$, Young-type inequalities are available: see [theorem 3.3 here](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~lvrmr/2008-2009-S/Classes/AMSC674/IntOps.pdf) and Theorem 2.2 in [Convolution Inequalities in Lorentz Spaces](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00041-010-9159-9) by  Nursultanov and  Tikhonov.